# Ext JS Code Package: Include resources/css/*.css in package build

Tags: extjs, sass, package, sencha-cmd

I have a CSS file in the *resources/css* directory of my Ext JS package. Nevertheless *package-all.css* is empty after the `sencha package build`.

**How can I make Sencha put the CSS file's contents into *package-all.css*? It should finally be copied to the *all.css* file of the app that uses the package.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add it to `package.json` as a resource.

```
/**
 * Extra resources to be copied along when build
 */
"resources": [
  "resources/css/app.css",
"resources/images",
"resources/static",
"resources/libs",
  "resources/translations"
],
```

or even better as a css file.

```
/**
 * List of all CSS assets in the right inclusion order.
 * Each item is an object with the following format:
 *      {
 *          "path": "path/to/item.css" // Path to file, if local file it must be relative to this app.json file
 *          "remote": true             // (Optional)
 *                                     // - Defaults to undefined (falsey) to signal a local file which will be copied
 *                                     // - Specify true if this file is a remote file which will not to be copied
 *          "update": "delta"          // (Optional)
 *                                     //  - If not specified, this file will only be loaded once, and
 *                                     //    cached inside localStorage until this value is changed to either one below
 *                                     //  - "delta" to enable over-the-air delta update for this file
 *                                     //  - "full" means full update will be made when this file changes
 *
 *      }
 */
"css": [
{
  "path": "resources/libs/Arcgis v3.11/arcgis311.css",
  "remote": true
},
{
  "path": "resources/css/app.css",
  "remote": true
}
]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to add it to the **-all.css* file which is loaded anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can include it directly to index.html. Its working fine in build as well.`

```
<title>xxxxx</title>

<!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Cmd to build your application -->
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='resources/custom/css/my_css.css' />
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='resources/fonts/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css' />
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
```

`

Comment: Sencha's best practice is to not edit the index.html file, because it is re-generated in the build process. Sencha even puts it into a comment, and what you do is ignore the comment and just add your own lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Tarabass' answer, I added my CSS file in **package.json** inside the package. Now it is used by the app.

```
"css": [{
  path: "resources/css/styles.css"
}],
```

Comment: Forgot that's called `package.json` instead of `app.json`. I will edit my answer to be more precise for future users who want to accomplish the same.